# Почему строки (light-height) наезжают друг на друга?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Никак не могу понять, почему строки при использования свойства light-height наезжают друг на друга, верстаю макет по PSD вроде все делаю правильно, подскажите, как сделать правильно, чтоб при light-height строки не наезжали друг на друга. P.S Мне нужно только правильное решение, просто взять и отодвинуть марджинами не годится. Я просто забыл, как правильно это делается. То есть, задаются стили шрифтам и отступам, чтоб все было корректно.

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaCond-Regular';
    color: #87949e;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

div, span, article, ul, li, a, button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    outline: 1px solid green;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1483px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: скопировал ваш CSS код - у меня всё нормально

Comment: @Артур Найт выставить font-size и  line-height  где у Вас body одинаковый размер?

Comment: В body у меня размер 18px line-height-30px, так и в PSD, но шрифт почему-то наезжает, такого не должно быть, я когда-то давно верстал и делал все правильно,. сейчас не много подзабыл

Comment: Все, спасибо за вашу помощь, я решил эту проблему. Я открыл файл в гугл хром - там нормально все работает, а в мозила шрифты наезжают друг-на друга, поэтому я добавил свойству light-height префикс -moz, и все сработало, как надо